# Create Array in cellForRowInIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to save an array of images that I retrieve asynchronously in the `cellForRowInIndexPath` method of the `UITableViewController`.

Unfortunately, the array is not fully populated or in incorrect order.

The code within my `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is:

```
// populate the cell's image
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[newsModel url]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    img = [[UIImage  alloc] initWithData:data] ;
    [imageArray insertObject:img atIndex:[indexPath row]];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // make image standard size
        CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        [img drawInRect:imageRect];

        cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    });
});
```

Both the imageArray (`NSMutableArray`) and img (`UIImage`) are of type `__bool`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to store into dictionary with  key inplace of array because no chances to duplication after that insert into array using `AllValue` of dictionary

For ex:

```
imageArray =[[dict allValues]mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[newsModel url]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
img = [[UIImage  alloc] initWithData:data] ;

[dict setObject:img forKey:indexPath.row]
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// make image standard size
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
[img drawInRect:imageRect];

cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[cell setNeedsLayout];
});
});
imageArray =[[dict allValues]mutableCopy];
```

Comment: That works.  Just needed to set key as object.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to modify the cell after the download has completed, you don't know if it's been reused. Just save the image and then ask the table view to `reloadData` (ensure you ask for the reload on the main thread).